# How to solve Untyped module error with Flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I am getting an error with flow:

> Importing a type from an untyped module makes it `any` and is not
>   safe! Did you mean to add `// @flow` to the top of `../types`?
>   (`untyped-type-import`)

This is some of the code in '../types' file .

```
   // @flow
   import type { Account } from '../../props/account'
   import type { Accrual } from '../../props/accrual-prop'
   import type { Amount } from '../../props/amount'
   import type { Customer } from '../../props/customer'
   import type { PaymentTerms } from '../../props/payment-terms'
   import type { NumberSeries } from '../../props/number-series'
   import type { SalesDocumentLock } from '../../props/lock-prop'

    export type Status = 'invoice'|'order'|'offer'

    export type CustomerContact = {
customerContactNumber: number,
name: string,
    }

    export type Employee = {
self?: ?string,
employeeNumber: number,
name: string,
    }

    export type AdditionalExpenseLine = {
additionalExpense: {
    additionalExpenseNumber: number,
    name: string,
    isSystemCreated: boolean
 },
vatAccount: VATAccount,
vatAmount?: ?number,
amount?: number,
grossAmount?:number,
isExcluded: boolean,
salesPricesEnteredInGross : boolean,
vatRate?:number,
additionalExpenseType: AdditionalExpenseType
    }
```

Comment: What steps to fix did you take so far? It's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing more files or more info about the error. Clearly you have `// @flow` at the top of this file so the obvious fix that Flow recommends isn't applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this that seemed to be caused by both exporting functions like:

`export function foo() {}`

and also having a

`module.exports = { ... }`

in the file as well.

Once I got rid of the `export function` statements the problem went away. (I had many `export type` statements in the file, and they were fine.)